# Wifi country (?) problem in ubuntu 18.04 and hotspot

Tags: networking, wireless, iwlwifi

So I just bought a laptop from an italian company [This](https://microtech.store/e-book-pro-specifiche/) with Ubuntu already installed. I am living in Mexico and when I tried to connect to the wifi it was either really slow or just did not work at all. I changed the country code to Mexico (MX) but I didn't see any changes. So I tried to use my smartphone to make hotspot, and connecting to this my laptop is perfect, fast and does not lose connection. What can it be? I specify that with the mexican wifi I never had a problem with my android smartphone and my old chromebook.